# I am using websocket protocol to request my springboot application,but heppened "org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound : No mapping for GET"

Tags: java, jquery, spring-boot, web, websocket

my fornt end is website I am using jquery frame to request a websocket request at web page loads and my server is a springboot application.

but the springboot application logs sad "org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound : No mapping for GET"

This is my code to implement the websocket request

```
//刷新页面时创建链接
        $(function(){
            //创建webSocket链接
            var ws = new WebSocket(serverWebSocketURL + "/empPoint");
            
            ws.onopen = function(evt){
                send("Hello world!!!");
            }
            
            ws.onmessage = function(evt){
                
            }
            
            ws.onerror = function(evt){
                
            }
            
            ws.onclose = function(evt){
                //关闭链路时打开
            }
        });
```

This is my code from springboot application server

```
package com.njustjjy.tpk2.endpoint;

import com.njustjjy.tpk2.config.GetHttpSessionConfig;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.websocket.*;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@Log4j2
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/empPoint",configurator = GetHttpSessionConfig.class)
@Component
public class EmpEndpoint {

    //生命session对象
    private Session session;
    //获取session
    private HttpSession httpSession;

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig endpointConfig){
        //将局部的session赋值到全局作用域
        this.session = session;
        //获取HttpSession
        this.httpSession = (HttpSession) endpointConfig.getUserProperties().get(HttpSession.class.getName());

    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session){
        System.out.print(message);
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable err){
        log.error("发生错误：" + err);
    }
}
```

This is JavaConfig in the springboot

```
package com.njustjjy.tpk2.config;

import com.njustjjy.tpk2.endpoint.EmpEndpoint;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class WebScoketConfig {
    @Bean
    public EmpEndpoint businessEndpoint(){
        return new EmpEndpoint();
    }
}
```

I am try some blogs but they are no any way,but I think this problem about tomcat support for websocket protocol.  Do I have any master to help me?